# Storing data on client side - How to protect against manipulation?

Tags: c#, php, security, encryption, data-integrity

**General/Introduction:**
I work on a project where we have two parts of software. There is a client application that runs on the user's computer and a web application that manages a lot of things related to this project.

The client application reads a lot of different values via IPC from another program, that I don't have the source code of and I don't have the option to change anything in that other program I am reading from.
So, my application collects those values and stores them locally, since it is not always connected to the web application.

Since the web application builds statistics and more out of those values and since the values that are collected are quite important for the whole project, the user should not be able to change them (or at least it should be really hard - I am pretty sure you can't provide 100 % security for data on the client).

Just for the sake of full information: The client application is written in C#, while the web application is based on the Laravel Framework (PHP). But this question is more about theory than exactly how to code this.

**My thoughts:**
I was thinking about having asymmetric encryption. The client encrypts the data with the public key of the web application server. The data is now stored encrypted. But of course, the client has this public key. Hence, an attacker could just go ahead and encrypt his own manipulated values and store them in the file.

Another thought, that builds upon the encryption, was that I could not only encrypt the data, but the whole file and use a format that is not too obvious. But that is more like security through obscurity and should be avoided as far as I know. Plus one could just decompile the client application and instantly have the format that I am using.

**My question:**
Is there any way I can provide a decent level of integrity when sending that data to the server? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: You can't. Any data that the client can touch can be considered compromised. The best and cleanest thing you can do is ensure data integrity once it reaches the Laravel backend.

Comment: That's what I was thinking... but sadly, the backend can at the most do plausibility checks. The web application can't ensure the integrity in this case. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: Maybe you can re-validate against the IPC data before sending to the web server.

Comment: You need to clarify from which threats you want to protect this. Can attacker access only raw data from disk or he can enter system under users credentials for example?

Comment: The "attacker" can access his user account. The program runs under his user account on his request. I want to protect the data I am reading to avoid manipulation of the server-side stats that are built from those values. Revalidation does not work, since the IPC data constantly changes during runtime of my program.

Comment: Well, you could protect it IF you had some access to the source app that you access via IPC. This technique is called `signing`. However, it is rather pointless here because if your client app reads source data 'raw' then there is nothing you can do about it. if you need to protect data from accidental edits, consider storing it in such a way that the end user can't access it. If it is to protect from actual malicious manipulation, you need to contact the manufacturer of the app that originates the date to see what secure interface they can add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

1. Give up, because [client software authenticity is not the server's problem](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem), and it's theoretically impossible to know for sure that the other end is running the software you intend in a way that isn't spoofable.
2. If you're using the client software as a data mule, use `hash_hmac()` and `hash_equals()` to authenticate the data so it's tamper-evident.

For example, you could store the MAC by prefixing it to the data:

```
$key = random_bytes(32); // Store me for long-term. Maybe per-client?

$data = "foo";
$mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $key);
echo $data . $mac;
```

And then to validate it upon being returned by the client software:

```
if (mb_strlen($message, '8bit') < 64) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid message length.");
}
$mac = mb_substr($message, 0, 64, '8bit');
$data = mb_substr($message, 64, null, '8bit');
$recalc = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $key);
if (!hash_equals($recalc, $mac)) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid MAC.");
}
// Now we know $data is legitimate.
```

It is important to use `hash_equals()` not `==` or `===` to prevent timing attacks.

Note that this renders any such data *unavoidably read-only*. If you want them to be able to edit data, you're stuck with option 1.